# Get data from hook procedure?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, callback, setwindowshookex

I have C++ DLL, that implements CTB_HOOK and c# app, from which I P/Invoke this DLL.

The system calls the function below when messages to hooked thread are intercepted (before activating, creating, destroying, minimizing, maximizing, moving, or sizing a window and so on). I want to pass `nCode` to my c# application.

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("HCBT_ACTIVATE"), TEXT("inside hook"), MB_OK);
    }
    //here I want to pass nCode(code of intercepted message) to my c# app.

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

At first tried to use a `callback` to C# from C++ code ([good article on this topic](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318140/How-to-make-a-callback-to-Csharp-from-C-Cplusplus)). But soon I've realized I have no way to a pass pointer to `c#_callback_function` to `CBTHookProc` (I wanted to save pointer to `c#_callback_function` as a global variable, but since each process using a DLL has its own instance of all the DLLs global nothing succeeded).

Then I googled for DLL share data, but I is only suitable for static variables.

So, is there a way to callback from hook procedure? Or maybe some other way to get data from hook procedure?

Comment: Since the DLL and the application run in different processes, you need to use one of the [interprocess communication mechanisms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx)

Comment: IPC will kick your brain out of proportion.